# Django/Python ImportError: No module named admin

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, importerror

As a result of attempting to update `admin.py` of one of my Django apps, I now get a Server Error (500) that has brought my site down. When I import admin from django.contrib, I get the following traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
     import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named admin
```

Using print_stack() gives me a little deeper insight:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/gather/src/foodshop/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
  application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
  django.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
  app_config.ready()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
  self.module.autodiscover()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
  autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
  import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File "/home/ubuntu/gather/src/recipes/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
  class RecipesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
File "/home/ubuntu/gather/src/recipes/admin.py", line 9, in RecipesAdmin
  traceback.print_stack()
```

I use this module in several other apps within my project, so I don't understand why it's not working for this particular app. You can see my very simple Python code below, which is for an admin.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Recipes

class RecipesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "rating", "date_modified"]
        prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("SKU",)}
        class Meta:
                model = Recipes

admin.site.register(Recipes, RecipesAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from djangoratings.views import AddRatingFromModel

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', 'customers.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', 'customers.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^about/', 'recipes.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^menu/', 'recipes.views.menu', name='menu'),
    url(r'^donate/', 'recipes.views.menu', name='menu'),
    # url(r'^contact/', 'recipes.views.contact', name='contact'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^about/healthy/', 'recipes.views.healthy', name='healthy'),
    url(r'^about/premade/', 'recipes.views.premade', name='premade'),
    url(r'^about/exceptional/', 'recipes.views.exceptional', name='exceptional'),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    url(r'^cart/', 'cart.views.get_cart', name='get_cart'),
    url(r'^add/', 'recipes.views.menu', name='menu'),
    # url(r'^add/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/id=(?P<quantity>[-\w]+)/$', 'cart.views.add_to_cart', name='shopping-cart-add'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'cart.views.specific_qty', name='shopping-cart-specify'),
    url(r'^remove/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'cart.views.remove_from_cart', name='shopping-cart-remove'),
    url(r'^subtract/(?P<product_id>[-\w]+)/$', 'cart.views.subtract_from_cart', name='shopping-cart-subtract'),
    url(r'^clear_cart/', 'cart.views.clear_cart', name='shopping-cart-clear'),

    url(r'^contact/$','contact.views.email',name='email'),
    url(r'^feedback/$','contact.views.feedback',name='feedback'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', 'contact.views.thanks',name='thanks'),
    url(r'^profile/$', 'cart.views.profile', name='profile'),
    url(r'^profile/new/$', 'cart.views.new_profile', name='new_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/error/$', 'cart.views.qty_error', name='qty_error'),
    url(r'^profile/cancel/$', 'cart.views.cancel_sub', name='cancel_sub'),
    url(r'^profile/feedback/$', 'recipes.views.feedback', name='feedback'),

    url(r'^rate/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<score>\d+)/', AddRatingFromModel(), {
        'app_label': 'recipes',
        'model': 'recipes',
        'field_name': 'rating',
    }),

    url(r'^charge/$', 'cart.views.charge', name='charge'),
    url(r'^subscription/charge/$', 'cart.views.pay', name='pay'),

    url(r'^frequently_asked/$', 'cart.views.frequently_asked', name='frequently_asked'),
    url(r'^tender/$', 'cart.views.weekly_orders', name='weekly_orders'),
    url(r'^tender_postmates/$', 'cart.views.tender_postmates', name='tender_postmates')

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have ensured that I am importing `django.contrib.admin` in settings.py, and in my urls.py file, I have `from django.contrib import admin` and `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`. This just started when I tried changing the admin.py file above; even after reverting back to the original file, the server error occurs. Unfortunately, this has brought my entire site down.

I'm using an Ubuntu machine and an Apache2 server. Any insights would be much appreciated!

**Update 1**: Even after doing a git reset --hard to origin/master, the error is still occurring.

**Update 2**: I have removed every `.pyc` file and restarted my Apache2 server, but the problem persists.

**Update 3**: In the manage.py shell, when I do `>>> from django.contrib import admin as a`, `>>> a` resolves to `<module 'django.contrib.admin' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py'>`. This explicitly shows the module exists, but the problem is still occurring.

Comment: try replacing `from models import Recipes` with `from .models import Recipes`

Comment: what's your urls.py ?

Comment: Apologies, the original file at origin/master was correct as .models. I made the edit above. That's not the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "have ensured that I am importing django.contrib.admin in settings.py"? You mean you add `django.contrib.admin` into `INSTALLED_APPS`, right? You should definitely not `import` it in there

Comment: You're right, "import" is not the correct term -- I added it in settings.py. In installed_apps, I added django.contrib.admin. That hasn't changed since I created the project and the app. My overarching point is that for 6 months, the site has been running, but as soon as I made a minor change to admin.py in my Recipes app (and nowhere else), the site came down. Even after reverting all the changes via git, I'm getting a server error for "No module named admin."

Comment: Could it be that a security / unattended update of one or more of your python modules have changed the underlying system? Sometimes you will only see the effect of that once the code is reloaded. It has happened to us in the past.

Comment: @acs254 found a solution ?